# Autowiring in classes without RequestMapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, autowired

I am working on three different tables. I am using Hibernate to query these tables. I implemented successfully the DAO and the service layers, but i have few problems with the controller package. Here is my code, my controller package contains 3 classes , each should handle a table (i have 3 tables as i said before).

```
@Controller
public class Ods_Gis_Actel_Controller {

    Param_Gis_Actel_Controller Param = new Param_Gis_Actel_Controller();
    Tbl_Dim_Actel_Controller Dim = new Tbl_Dim_Actel_Controller();


    @Autowired
    Ods_Gis_Actel_metier service;

    @RequestMapping(value="/index")
    public String pageIndex(Model model)
    {   
        addOdsTable(model);
        Param.addParamTable(model);
        Dim.addDimTable(model);
        return "Affichage";
    }

    public void addOdsTable(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("listeOds",service.getAll());
    }

}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class Param_Gis_Actel_Controller {

    @Autowired
    Param_Gis_Actel_metier service;

    public void addParamTable(Model model)
    { 
    model.addAttribute("listeParam",service.getAll());
    }

}




@Controller
public class Tbl_Dim_Actel_Controller {

    @Autowired
    Tbl_Dim_Actel_metier service;

    public void addDimTable(Model model)
    {
    model.addAttribute("listeDim",service.getAll());
    }

}
```

The request mapping is done in the 1st class, whose method calls 2 other methods from the  other classes.  But it seems, that **the autowiring** works only in the class, where the RequestMapping is performed.

Is this true?

how can i use the other methods from the classes which don't contain the RequestMapping if the autowiring doesn't work for them?

Answer (score 1):

I gone through your problem , I think you are not so much aware the objective of @Controller , @RequestMapping . So First of all you need to know , why we use @Controller?, this is used to give business logic to your request. When request is hited from  user , then your DispatcherServlet match the url from your request to value of RequestMapping annotation of all defined controller. And according to that , the matched mapping method is called and further procees done by framework. Now come to @Autowire, this is used to load the bean class definition from the xml configuration. So the @Autowire and @RequestMapping having different objective . So it's wrong to say here that the

`**autowiring** works only in the class where the RequestMapping is performed.`

Now your second question , How you can use simple class? there are two ways to achieve that as far as I know,
1) To create the Object of that class inside your class as you done in your code
2) To create the instance of that class using factory-method.

for the second point , you have to first define your class inside the configuration file by following the below format

```
<bean id="paramGis" class="<whatever_package_detail>.Param_Gis_Actel_Controller" factory-method="createInstance"/>
```

here one things you have to care that this method should be static .

and your class would look like that

```
@Service
public class Param_Gis_Actel_Controller {


    private static Param_Gis_Actel_Controller  paramGis;

    public static Param_Gis_Actel_Controller createInstance(){
                 if(paramGis==null){
                       return new Param_Gis_Actel_Controller();
                 }
         return paramGis;
    }

    public void addParamTable(Model model)
    { 
    model.addAttribute("listeParam",service.getAll());
    }

}
```

If you are still getting problem let me know.

Comment: my question is shortly, are all the attributes with @autowired annotations in my program, "autowired" automatically in any class of my controller package even if the class containing the attribute isn't handled by the Spring (i mean called with spring based on the url the user calls)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having difficulties with the Java/Spring way. We don't use `@Controller/@Autowired` like that.

It's kind of hard to explain shortly (I strongly recommend you read the [official document](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller) for that), but in short, you shouldn't create a Controller object inside another controller. The objects with annotation marks (`@Controller`, `@Service`...) should be generated and managed by Spring. At initiation time they will be injected with the `@Autowired` services by "Spring" way. Of courses you can intervene into that process, but by other special methods.

P/s: your naming convention is not for Java ;). If you create a program for personal use it maybe ok, but you will have difficult times collaborating with other Java developers.

Comment: my question is shortly, are all the attributes with @autowired annotations in my program, "autowired" automatically in any class of my controller package even if the class containing the attribute isn't handled by the Spring (i mean called with spring based on the url the user calls)

Comment: @user2627156: I think you mistake my answer with Ashish. However, for your question: I don't understand it. The Autowiring step isn't related to URL user calls - it is made when Spring initates your bean (most likely when the web application starts). Spring will try to autowire to your objects (Ods_Gis_Actel_Controller), but NOT into the object of Param_Gis_Actel_Controller inside of Ods_Gis_Actel_Controller.

Comment: i see. So all the objects with @autowired annotation, are initialised when the application starts (all of them),  ?

Comment: that's the default way. After checking your code, I think the two controllers are more like services. You should simply downgrade them to @Service and autowire them to the Controller Ods. AFAIK, there's no multi-level controller practice in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Through method name as default one for access that particular method or use @Qualifier annotations.